# Call array ['items'] not working

Tags: php, arrays

I have problem with my array, when i try var dump my aray is show like this

Example : `var_dump($mastervendor->listvendor());`

result is : `array(3) { ["items"]=> object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(6358) ["type"]=> int(0) } ["count"]=> int(6358) ["exist"]=> bool(true) }`

But when i try call  `var_dump($mastervendor->listvendor()['items']);`

it said `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Why i cant call `['items']`??? Did i do something worng??

my php is `PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4`

Comment: I don't believe you can reference an array location off a method call until like php 5.5. Try saving result to an intermediate variable.

Comment: @JeffPuckett : Well i got that result when i try that.. I dont know if that method call in php 5.5. So how do i change intermediate variable??

Comment: 5 going on 6 year old version of php, maybe time for an upgrade.

Comment: @rtfm : Well if i could change old version, cause that sevrer php not from my computer but from another computer wich i cant remote or i dont have authority to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my php is PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4

Since PHP 5.4 it's possible:

Source : https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-62

till then

```
$some_variable = $mastervendor->listvendor();
print_r($some_variable['items']);
```

On PHP `5.3` or earlier, you have to use a temporary variable.

Comment: Omg You save me!! Thats working!!! Tq very much.

Comment: @Wolfzmus: you are most welcome

Comment: Downvoter throw your comment also, what's wrong here ????

Comment: i dont know. lol